# Laravel 5.2 Multi-Auth with API guard uses wrong table

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I'm trying to get a multi-auth system working where Users can log in via the normal web portal, but a separate database of entities (named "robots" for example) can also log in via an API guard token driver. But no matter what I do, the setup I have is not directing my authentication guard to the correct Robot database and keeps trying to authenticate these requests as Users via tokens (which fails, because users don't have tokens).

Can someone help me find where I've gone wrong?

I've started by putting together a middleware group in Kernel.php:

```
'api' => [
    'throttle:60,1',
        'auth:api',
],
```

This uses settings in config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'robots',
        ],
    ],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'robots' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Robot::class,
    ],
],
```

The middleware gets called in routes.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'api'], function () {
    Route::get('api/request', 'API\RequestController@index');
});
```

It uses this model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;

class Robots extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'serial_number','api_token',
    ];
    protected $guard = 'Robots';

    protected $hidden = [
        'api_token',
    ];
}
```

Any ideas?

**Update:** on further inspection, it appears that most of the settings in auth.php are not applying properly - is there some way I can force these settings to take effect?

Comment: Using web service?

Comment: What do you mean? I'm not using the web middleware, since that will throw a token exception for API calls.

Comment: if using API then pass api_token on header

Comment: Right, that's what I'd like to do. However, when I pass the API token in the header, it attempts to authenticate using the User provider instead of the Robot provider like I want it to, and throws an SQL error because Users don't have an API token column in their table. It's as if it's completely ignoring the config/auth.php file.

Comment: add field api_token on App\Models\Robot table.

Comment: ... I have that. My problem is that it is redirecting to Users, not Robots. It never even hits the Robots table.

Comment: create new middleware for robots.

Comment: Solved your issue or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actual issue/solution:

Laravel has a separate, rarely mentioned cache that exists exclusively for its config files. Normal cache and class reset methods like `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan cache:clear` do not affect this cache, which was leading to my confusing state of having none of the settings in my auth.php file take effect.

The correct way to clear this cache is to use the commands:

`php artisan config:cache`

`php artisan config:clear`

These resolved my issue.

Answer (score 3):

In your config/auth.php you specify the provided model to be used for robots provider: `'model' => App\Models\Robot::class` However your Robot class is defined as `class Robots extends Authenticatable`, which is a mismatch of the class name.

Rename your class to `class Robot`

Comment: Authenticatable is required for the class to use the Token driver, I think. Additionally, why would the extension syntax change the name of the class?

Comment: Your class name is Robots (plural). Rename it to Robot (singular)

Comment: I see. This is a good catch but was not actually the issue I was having (see below). I'll give you the bounty reward for it though, thanks for looking it over!